Can we find four identically colored numbers?
Take the positive integers {1, 2, 3, ...} and color them red, green or blue.  Is it true that no matter what coloring is chosen, we can always find three distinct numbers x, y and z so that x, y, z and x+y+z are all the same color?

This puzzle was inspired by:  How do we find the numbers?

This puzzle implies the answer is yes, though the weaker condition here might allow a nicer and more accessible argument.

With computer programs, I found that {1, ..., 93} allows a quad-free coloring but {1, ..., 94} doesn't. Doesn't feel like a useful insight though.

@xnor I saw that puzzle after I posted my question and I debated whether I should delete my question or not.  I decided to keep my question because I am hoping my weaker constraint can lead to an elegant solution.

Is 3, 6, 9, and 18 satisfy you?

@Moti If 3=red, 6=red, 9=green, 18=blue, then your choice of numbers won’t work because the numbers are not all the same color.  Notice the following phrase in the question:  “no matter what coloring is chosen ...”.

It would be better to write " '''and color them RANDOMLY...":)

@Moti The phrase, “no matter what coloring is chosen ...” is meant to include all possible colorings including all random colorings.

@Bubbler generalizing it into {1, ..., N} and K colours might be a better insight.

Did you solve it?

@Moti I haven’t solved it.

@Bubbler the answer seems to suggest the integers from 1 to 73 already doesn't allow a quad free coloring. Can you confirm that with your program? (Also, how would you go about writing this program?)

@BenjaminWang Picat script to find a quad free coloring for 1..93, cross checked in Python.

@Bubbler thank you for introducing me to Picat!

Does a solution exist?

Yes.

Proof:

Label the vertices of a graph from $0$ to $n$. Between every pair of vertices $x<y$, draw an edge with the color of $2^y-2^x$. By Ramsey's theorem, for large enough $n$, there exist vertices $w<x<y<z$ such that the edges between every pair have the same color. Then $2^x-2^w$, $2^y-2^x$, and $2^z-2^y$ are distinct and have the same color as their sum $2^z-2^w$.


This solution was inspired by this one.

Nice answer. It's fun to note that you have a (very loose) bound of $2^{236}$.

@BenjaminWang If we use the Ramsey number for 4-cycles this improves to $2^{10}$(!) (not a factorial)

Nice. Do you have a source or proof that $R(C_4,C_4,C_4)\le 10$?

@BenjaminWang It's $11$ (so $2^0$ to $2^{10}$) according to various papers which cite this one.

What is the justification for using the powers of 2? Is it sufficient to use any sequence for which all differences between two elements are distinct?

@AxiomaticSystem That's correct, only distinctness is necessary.

A005282 begins 1, 2, 4, 8, 13, 21, 31, 45, 66, 81, 97..., which almost brings your bound all the way down to Bubbler's computer result. If a non-greedy sequence yields a smaller eleventh term, that would be even better.

@AxiomaticSystem Good point! Then we can use the length of the optimal Golomb ruler with 11 marks, which according to A003022 is 72. Strangely, this seems to beat Bubbler's result?

The construction does not consider cycles that visit the vertices in a "wrong" order, such as w->y->x->z or w->x->z->y, so I think $R(C_4, C_4, C_4)$ is not the right number to use.

@Bubbler Good catch, you specifically need to use the greatest edge, between the least and greatest vertices in the clique, but a cycle might have that pair nonadjacent.
